# Selenium C# ElementNotFound Exception Handling

Tags: c#, selenium, exception

I am running a case in Selenium where I want to verify that all elements are displayed on a web page but only want custom asserts to display at the end of the test if one or more cannot be found.  Currently, using driver.FindElement, I cannot get past the ElementNotFound exceptions when assigning elements to variables if they are not there at time of identification.  Is there any way around this?  Here is my current code

```
        IWebElement userIcon = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        userIcon.Click();


        IWebElement profileIcon = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1)"));
        profileIcon.Click();


        IWebElement headerLogo = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".company-logo"));


        IWebElement headerMsgDrop = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".fa-envelope-o"));
        headerMsgDrop.Click();
        IWebElement headerMsgDropSubGeneral = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2)"));


        Assert.Multiple(() =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(headerLogo.Displayed, "Header Logo NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerMsgDrop.Displayed, "Header Main Message Drop NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerMsgDropSubGeneral.Displayed, "Header - Message - General Option NOT Present");
        });


        IWebElement headerUserDrop = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        headerUserDrop.Click();
        IWebElement headerUserDropSubProfile = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".user-name"));
        IWebElement headerUserDropSubCredentials = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        IWebElement headerUserDropSubSettings = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        IWebElement headerUserDropSubChgPass = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        IWebElement headerUserDropSubRstGrid = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clearLocalStorage"));
        IWebElement headerUserDropSubLogOff = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)"));


        Assert.Multiple(() =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(headerUserDrop.Displayed, "Header Main User Drop NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerUserDropSubProfile.Displayed, "Header - User - Profile Option NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerUserDropSubCredentials.Displayed, "Header - User - Credentials Option NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerUserDropSubSettings.Displayed, "Header - User - Settings Option NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerUserDropSubChgPass.Displayed, "Header - User - Change Password Option NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerUserDropSubRstGrid.Displayed, "Header - User - Reset Grid Option NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerUserDropSubLogOff.Displayed, "Header - User - Log off Option NOT Present");
        });


        IWebElement headerSupportDrop = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        headerSupportDrop.Click();
        IWebElement headerSupportDropSubBase = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(4) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        IWebElement headerSupportDropSubFaq = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(4) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)"));
        IWebElement headerSupportDropSubTicket = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.dropdown:nth-child(4) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)"));


        Assert.Multiple(() =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(headerSupportDrop.Displayed, "Header Main Support Drop NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerSupportDropSubBase.Displayed, "Header - Support - Knowledge Base Option NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerSupportDropSubFaq.Displayed, "Header - Support - FAQ Option NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(headerSupportDropSubTicket.Displayed, "Header - Support - Submit Request Option NOT Present");
        });


        IWebElement emailTextInputField = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.col-md-10:nth-child(2)"));
        IWebElement saveBut = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn"));
        IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));


        Assert.Multiple(() =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains("Profile"),"Profile Text NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains("Email"),"Email Text NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(body.Text.Contains("© 2018 - Stage Front Tickets"),"Copyright Text NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(emailTextInputField.Displayed, "Email Text Input Field NOT Present");
            Assert.IsTrue(saveBut.Displayed, "Save Button NOT Present");
        });


        driver.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Here are two articles on exception handling and (re)throwing I link a lot: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this kind of solution:

```
    public IWebElement Get(By byLocator, double seconds = 10)
    {
        IWebElement element = null;

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        try
        {
            element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byLocator));
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return element;
    }
```

Or you can wait for it to be clickable also.

```
ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(byLocator)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not waiting or you are not giving UI to load properly before capturing the next element and perform certain action on it.

You need to add some wait time before performing next step.
Eg. waitTillElementPresent